# Knockout -> Bind to Nested Structure, where Children can be null

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, binding

I use knockout to build a Visualization Application, which could bind to Values. Problem is, sometimes I bind to a Path ("aa.bb.cc.dd") where a child could be undefined (cc = undefined). Then, no binding should happen, it should be ignored!

This could work if I nest this in several div's and use with binding, but all of this is done in code behind, and I would not like the Idea of having so many nested divs! Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three options:

(1) Handle the nullable fields via nested bindings (as mentioned)

```
<!-- ko if: aa() -->
<!-- ko if: aa().bb() -->
<!-- ko if: aa().bb().cc() -->
<input data-bind="value: aa().bb().cc().dd"></input>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

(2) Build a computable that traverses the tree and returns null if needed

```
thing.bindableDD = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    if (thing.aa()) {
        if (thing.aa().bb()) {
            if (thing.aa().bb().cc()) {
               return thing.aa().bb().cc().dd;
            } else return null;
        } else return null;
    } else return null;
};

<input data-bind="value: bindableDD"></input>
```

(3) Create a custom binding that checks for undefined values.
I've never created a custom binding handler so maybe someone else could assist with the format but I think it'd have this in it:

```
try {
    value(); // try to access it
} catch (e) {
    return null;
}

<input data-bind="nullableValue: thing.aa().bb().cc().dd"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the eval function to traverse through the path. If this path does not exist, simply return null and knockout will not render the element.

Something like this:

```
  <div data-bind="text: traverse('this.a1().b().c().d')"/>
  <div data-bind="text: traverse('this.a2().b().c().d')"/>
  <script>
    var ViewModel = function() {
      this.a1 = ko.observable({b: ko.observable({c: ko.observable({ d: 'd value' })})});
      this.a2 = ko.observable({b: ko.observable()});
      this.traverse = function(path) {
        try {
          return eval(path);
        } catch(err) {
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: But I'd like to render the element, i will only not bind the property!

Comment: The return '' on the catch(err) and knockout will render the element, showing empty on its content. That's what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I've now solved it by changing in knockout.js line 2597 from:

```
 val = 'function(){return ' + val + ' }';
```

to:

```
 val = 'function(){try{return ' + val + ' }catch(e){console.warn(\''+val.replace(/'/g,"\"")+' - undefined property in path\');}}';
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest trying another route to fix your issue lest you create untraceable errors later on by modifying third-party packages without fully understanding the ramifications.